Align line points to each column in group
First is there a way to have line points align with with each of the quarters shown, I didn't find a similar demo or should I approach it differently?
Second is it possible to have one legend for all the columns so, when I click it hides all columns?
Right now it just grows and stretches outside what I want: https://codepen.io/rKaiser/pen/yLmePJZ
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'column'
},
title: {
    text: 'Quarterly Data with Aligned Line Graph and Spacing'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['2021', '2022', '2023'],
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    // Add spacing between each year group
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    labels: {
        style: {
            fontSize: '12px'
        }
    }
},
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: 'Values'
    }
},
tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true
},
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        //pointPadding: 0.2, // Padding between individual columns
        //groupPadding: 2.4  // Padding between groups of columns
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'Q1',
    data: [
        Math.random() * 100, // Q1 2021
        Math.random() * 100, // Q1 2022
        Math.random() * 100  // Q1 2023
    ]
}, {
    name: 'Q2',
    data: [
        Math.random() * 100, // Q2 2021
        Math.random() * 100, // Q2 2022
        Math.random() * 100  // Q2 2023
    ]
}, {
    name: 'Q3',
    data: [
        Math.random() * 100, // Q3 2021
        Math.random() * 100, // Q3 2022
        Math.random() * 100  // Q3 2023
    ]
}, {
    name: 'Q4',
    data: [
        Math.random() * 100, // Q4 2021
        Math.random() * 100, // Q4 2022
        Math.random() * 100  // Q4 2023
    ]
}, {
    name: 'Q1',
    type: 'line',
    data: [
        Math.random() * 100, // Q1 2021
        Math.random() * 100, // Q1 2022
        Math.random() * 100, // Q1 2023
        Math.random() * 100, // Q2 2021
        Math.random() * 100, // Q2 2022
        Math.random() * 100  // Q2 2023
        // need to match the quarters
    ]
}]

});
Added an image what I mean:

Thanks!

You can hide all the series with clicking one legend item using linkedTo property.
API reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.linkedTo
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/up9f5yba/
series: [
    {
      name: "columns series",
      id: "mainColumnSeries",
    },
    {
      name: "Q1",
      linkedTo: "mainColumnSeries",
      showInLegend: false,
      data: [
        Math.random() * 100, // Q1 2021
        Math.random() * 100, // Q1 2022
        Math.random() * 100, // Q1 2023
      ]
    }
]

Unfortunately it's not possible to align the line points like that. You might add those lines using SVG Renderer like that: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n3xdoj0v/ or change the way how line series is created but these solution are quite demanding.
